# Android: failing on building release apk

Tags: android, gradle

Is there any difference between running ./gradlew assembleRelease and ./gradlew app:assembleRelease. For some reason, the first one is not working for me, but the second one works just fine

Answer (score 0):

`./gradlew app:assembleRelease` runs task named `assembleRelease` in module `app` whereas `./gradlew assembleRelease` does that for *all* modules that has task with this name registered

You can run `./gradlew assembleRelease -m` to see what tasks will be executed and to verify that it does run the `app:assembleRelease` too.

> For some reason, the first one is not working for me, but the second one works just fine

What do you mean by "*not working*"? I assume you mean it does not produce output `apk` file - where do you look for output artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

## Just copy his lines in Proguard-rules.pro file

```
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontobfuscate
-forceprocessing
-optimizationpasses 5

-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class * extends android.app.Activity

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static *** v(...);
  public static *** d(...);
  public static *** i(...);
  public static *** w(...);
  public static *** e(...);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Formato inválido ou desconhecido do arquivo /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.cprextract.rarzip/files/_rartemp_open_1573205040128/filename.ext